# Importing Anything in a Java Library Module says 'Cannot resolve symbol' in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

After creating a new empty project in android studio, I created a new module for Java or Kotlin library. But in the java class file keywords such as **String, System** shows **'Cannot resolve symbol'** error. I've tried few things like **clean project, rebuild project, invalidate cache/restart** etc. nothing worked. I also **updated gradle version**. I'm using android studio **Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 patch 4**.
What can I do in this situation.
[Project layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xzhN.png)

Comment: Have you checked your project layout;to make sure everything is in the correct place? It may be necessary to add the project layout to your question.

Comment: Layout image has been added.